# How to represent a coordinate system precessing around the centre of force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, rotational-dynamics, centrifugal-force

Is the centre of force same as the centre of mass of two rotating objects? If we set the coordinate system that is precessing around the centre of force, it will be a non-inertial frame of reference. How to formulate this mathematically so the pseudo-forces are automatically accounted for? I am unable to visualise this frame of reference in a diagram.